# Co-routine returns None for every alternate iteration

Tags: python-3.x, yield, coroutinescope

I have a piece of code as shown below:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
import logging


def consumer():
    while True:
        x = yield
        print(x)

def producer(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        x = int(input())
        yield x


def rooter():
    logging.info("Running the rooter")
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        yield math.sqrt(value)


def squarer():
    logging.info("Running the squarer")
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        print("from squarer: {}".format(value))
        yield value * value


def accumulator():
    logging.info("Running the accumulator.")
    running_total = 0
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        running_total += value
        yield running_total


def pipeline(prod, workers, cons):
    logging.info("workers: {}".format(workers))
    for num in prod:
        for i, w in enumerate(workers):
            num = w.send(num)
        cons.send(num)
    for worker in workers:
        worker.close()
    cons.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    order = input().strip()
    m = int(input())

    prod = producer(m)

    cons = consumer()
    next(cons)

    root = rooter()
    next(root)

    accumulate = accumulator()
    next(accumulate)

    square = squarer()
    next(square)

    pipeline(prod, eval(order), cons)
```

Sample input

```
[square, accumulate]
3  <- Number of inputs coming further

1  <- actual inputs
2
3
```

Sample Output

```
*The output should be as below:*
1
5
14
```

but comes to 
`10`(sum of the squares of `1` and `3`) when it should actually be  `14` (sum of the squares of `1`, `2`, `3`)

So essentially the input `2` is missed (It's second in the line of inputs).
On debugging further I found that this is the case for every alternate iteration, not just for the provided inputs here.

I am not able to decipher what's happening. If it's of any help, the co-routine `squarer` is the one returning `None` in the second iteration.
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide a concise example of your problem... this currently requires unknown input at runtime and presents pdb.

Comment: Please check now. @Attie

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this.

It's that we prime the co-routine after use in the `pipeline` function so the code becomes as follows: I have marked the `next(w)` line within asterix for reference.

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
import logging


def consumer():
    while True:
        x = yield
        print(x)

def producer(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        x = int(input())
        yield x


def rooter():
    logging.info("Running the rooter")
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        yield math.sqrt(value)


def squarer():
    logging.info("Running the squarer")
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        print("from squarer: {}".format(value))
        yield value * value


def accumulator():
    logging.info("Running the accumulator.")
    running_total = 0
    while True:
        value = (yield)
        running_total += value
        yield running_total


def pipeline(prod, workers, cons):
    logging.info("workers: {}".format(workers))
    for num in prod:
        for i, w in enumerate(workers):
            num = w.send(num)
            **next(w)**
        cons.send(num)
    for worker in workers:
        worker.close()
    cons.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    order = input().strip()
    m = int(input())

    prod = producer(m)

    cons = consumer()
    next(cons)

    root = rooter()
    next(root)

    accumulate = accumulator()
    next(accumulate)

    square = squarer()
    next(square)

    pipeline(prod, eval(order), cons)
```

As mentioned in [PEP specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#introduction) it says that a generator function's `yield`
is always `None` when resumed by a normal `next` call. So when explicitly made to `yield`, it'll be ready to handle the next input immediately in this case.